# Jenkins runnning on kubernetes throw errors after pod restart

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I am running Jenkins on kubernetes. After the last recreation of the pod, it is not working. This is how my logs look like:

```
webroot: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2020-09-04 07:13:09.168+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log#initialized: Logging initialized @468ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
2020-09-04 07:13:09.330+0000 [id=1] INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
2020-09-04 07:13:09.369+0000 [id=1] WARNING o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
2020-09-04 07:13:09.438+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-9.4.30.v20200611; built: 2020-06-11T12:34:51.929Z; git: 271836e4c1f4612f12b7bb13ef5a92a927634b0d; jvm 1.8.0_242-b08
2020-09-04 07:13:10.209+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2020-09-04 07:13:10.277+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2020-09-04 07:13:10.278+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2020-09-04 07:13:10.285+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.server.session.HouseKeeper#startScavenging: node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
2020-09-04 07:13:10.866+0000 [id=1] INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: /var/jenkins_home found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2020-09-04 07:13:11.055+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@24105dc5{Jenkins v2.235.5,/,file:///var/jenkins_home/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/jenkins_home/war}
2020-09-04 07:13:11.094+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStart: Started ServerConnector@90f6bfd{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2020-09-04 07:13:11.094+0000 [id=1] INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: Started @2395ms
2020-09-04 07:13:11.100+0000 [id=20]    INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Winstone Servlet Engine running: controlPort=disabled
2020-09-04 07:13:13.253+0000 [id=26]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started initialization
2020-09-04 07:13:14.759+0000 [id=28]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Listed all plugins
2020-09-04 07:13:14.866+0000 [id=25]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: API v2.40 (workflow-api)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Pipeline: API (2.40)
 - Plugin is missing: scm-api (2.2.6)
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:934)
    at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:548)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1131)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-09-04 07:13:15.380+0000 [id=26]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin JUnit Plugin v1.26.1 (junit)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: JUnit Plugin (1.26.1)
 - Failed to load: Pipeline: API (2.40)
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:934)
    at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:548)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1131)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Once I describe the pod, I can see that the healthcheck is failing

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age   From                                                  Message
  ----     ------     ----  ----                                                  -------
  Normal   Scheduled  12m   default-scheduler                                     Successfully assigned infrastructure/jenkins-694d964d7-w9xnp to ip-172-20-111-99.eu-west-1.compute.internal
  Normal   Pulling    11m   kubelet, ip-172-20-111-99.eu-west-1.compute.internal  pulling image "jenkins/jenkins:lts"
  Normal   Pulled     11m   kubelet, ip-172-20-111-99.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Successfully pulled image "jenkins/jenkins:lts"
  Normal   Created    11m   kubelet, ip-172-20-111-99.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Created container
  Normal   Started    11m   kubelet, ip-172-20-111-99.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Started container
  Normal   Pulling    1m    kubelet, ip-172-20-111-99.eu-west-1.compute.internal  pulling image "jenkins/jenkins:lts"
  Normal   Pulled     1m    kubelet, ip-172-20-111-99.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Successfully pulled image "jenkins/jenkins:lts"
  Normal   Created    1m    kubelet, ip-172-20-111-99.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Created container
  Normal   Started    1m    kubelet, ip-172-20-111-99.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Started container
  Warning  Unhealthy  5s    kubelet, ip-172-20-111-99.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Readiness probe failed: Get http://100.111.168.195:8080/login: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Pod status looks like this:
`jenkins-694d964d7-w9xnp   0/1   Running:0/1   0  8m`

Any idea how can I fix this? I am not a Jenkins/kubernetes expert and I inherited this configuration. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: did it work? how you installed jenkins on kubernetes? give pods list. Have you tried to check wehats wrong with [scm-api](https://plugins.jenkins.io/scm-api/) plugin? any changes in  jenkins versions?

Comment: @Vitalii It worked until yesterday. Jenkins was installed using helms. 

I can see the pod is not created propely

`jenkins-694d964d7-w9xnp                                     0/1       Running:0/1   0          8m`

I have also added the Events part of the pod in the description

Answer (score 1):

This may/may not help. Try running:

```sh
kubectl describe pod [pod_id_jenkins-694d964d7-w9xnp]
```

and you may get some additional information. Looks like whatever config you're providing isn't sufficient to result in the application starting up properly, hence when the healthcheck is performed for the application the request times out and kubernetes reports that the application startup failed.

There's also this line:

```sh
2020-09-04 07:13:14.866+0000 [id=25]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: API v2.40 (workflow-api)
```

I've no idea what `Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: API v2.40 (workflow-api)` is but seems it fails.